# Facebook friends

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I am trying this code and I have problem with it problem is it is returning only single friends or registered friends

**Code :**

```
new Request(
                FacebookVariables.fbSession,
                "/me/friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        System.out.println("Friends Data "+response);
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
```

FacebookVariables.fbSession, is my custom variable

Comment: Facebook policy has been change significantly, now you can only access those friends data who have installed your application, unless you have got prior permission from facebook going through there approval process.

This new facebook policy has almost invalidated any data outside your own realm, read there new policy for more detail.

Comment: And thank heavens for that change, @Techfist

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void getFriendList() {
        FRIEND_LIST = new ArrayList<entProductFeedItemsComments>();//array list of class
        String fqlQuery = "SELECT name,uid,pic  FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY name";
        Bundle _params = new Bundle();
        _params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
        Session _session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Request _request = new Request(_session, "/fql", _params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    if (graphObject.getProperty("data") != null) {
                        try {
                            String _arry = graphObject.getProperty("data").toString();
                            JSONArray _jsonArray = new JSONArray(_arry);
                            if (_jsonArray.length() == 0) {
                                TV_NO_RECORD.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                TV_NO_RECORD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                for (int i = 0; i < _jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject _jsonObject = _jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    //fill up your data here 
                                    entProductFeedItemsComments _friendList = new entProductFeedItemsComments(getApplicationContext());
                                    _friendList.setUSER_NAME(_jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                    _friendList.setUSER_FRIEND_ID(_jsonObject.getString("uid"));
                                    _friendList.setPROFILE_PICTURE_PATH(_jsonObject.getString("pic"));
                                    FRIEND_LIST.add(_friendList);
                                }
                                //Set up your adpter here 

                                PROGRESSBAR.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            if (ex != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(_request);
        PROGRESSBAR.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Try this and let me know the result !!!